# Override object equals

Tags: java, set, hashset

I have this method:

```
private static void searchChannelByName(String name, ArrayList<VeediChannel> channel,HashSet<VeediChannel> newChannelsList)
{
    if(channel!=null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < channel.size(); i++) {
            if (channel.get(i).getName().toUpperCase().contains(name))
                newChannelsList.add(channel.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

I want to override to set the logic in which the set add is done (for preventing duplicates) so in VeediChannel class i am doing this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    Log.i(Utils.TAG,"In equals");
    if(this.getName().equals(((VeediChannel) o).getName()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

So when the add method is called on the newChannelsList the equals is supposed to be called

but, when checking the logs the equals method dont get call at all
What seems to be the problem?

Comment: if you override `equals` don´t forget to override `hashCode` aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you override `equals` without overriding `hashCode`, the `add` method of `HashSet` may look for the added element in the wrong bucket, and if there are no entries in that bucket, `equals` will never be called.

Even if you overridden both `equals` and `hashCode`, it's possible that `equals` won't be called when adding elements to the `HashSet`, if there are no duplicates and each element happens to be mapped to a different bucket.

Your `hashCode` implementation must be compatible with the `equals` implementation. For example:

```
@Override
public int hashCode ()
{
    return getName().hashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding to a `HashSet`, which does not normally use `equals` unless there is a collision. It looks like for the set you are constructing, there are no collisions, which means that the default hashing algorithm is using its job.

However, you will want to override your `hashCode` method in addition to `equals`. The basic requirement is that two equal object must have the same hash value. A simple implementation that satisfies this condition is

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    Log.i(Utils.TAG,"In hashCode");
    return this.getName().hashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, you must override `hashCode()` as well.
Here's a good detailed answer on this theme: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/3941803